# Промежуток чисел в Python

Tags: python, числа

Есть задача, в которой нужно вывести значение `True` если 
 пользовательская переменная принадлежит определенному промежутку чисел.

Как указать питону этот промежуток чисел и как указать, что в некоторых промежутках начальные/конечные числа включатся, а в некоторых нет.

для примера такие промежутки:

```
(−14,11]∪(13,16)∪[18,+∞) = True
else: False
```

Comment: Вводимые числа целые или вещественные?

Answer (score 3):

```
if -14 < x <= 11 or 13 < x < 16 or x >= 18:
    output = True
else:
    output = False
```

Comment: Лучше использовать  -14 < x <= 11  вместо  x in range(-14, 11)

Comment: все исправил, хоть и поздновато :P